# Convert C# Console App Into Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, singleton, console-application, singleton-type

I would like to turn my C# console application into Windows Forms Application. I designed my GUI with 3 textfields and one button. When I click the button I want the info from the 3 textfields to be added to my sql server database in Teachers table.

[My GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2sjw.png)

I have a Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public string name;
    public string familyName;
    public int age;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a list of teachers and a function to add in the sql server database using singleton:

```
public class TeacherData
{
    private static TeacherData _teacherData = new TeacherData();

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    private TeacherData()
    {
        Teachers = new List<Teacher>();
    }

    public static TeacherData GetInstance()
    {
        if (_teacherData == null)
            _teacherData = new TeacherData();
        return _teacherData;
    }

    public void AddTeacher(List<Teacher> Teachers)
    {
        var teacherData = TeacherData.GetInstance();

        //Get all students in the singleton
        var teachers = teacherData.Teachers;
        string ans = "";
        do
        {
            int tempInt;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter new teacher information");

            Console.Write(" 2. Enter teacher Name: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write(" 3. Enter teacher Family name: ");
            var familyName = Console.ReadLine();

            do
            {
                Console.Write(" 4. Enter teacher age: ");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInt));
            var age = tempInt;

            teacherData.Teachers.Add(new Teacher
            {
                Name = name,
                FamilyName = familyName,
                Age = age
            });

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {                    
                conn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-GSQLSQ5;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=true";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TEACHERS (NAME, FAMILY_NAME, AGE) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", conn);

                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", name));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", familyName));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("2", age));          
            }

            foreach (Teacher t in teachers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add another Teacher? y/n");
            ans = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (ans != "n");
    }
```

In the main function I call the add function like that :

```
        var teacherData = TeacherData.GetInstance();
        var teachers = teacherData.Teachers;
        teacherData.AddTeacher(teachers);
```

In other words, I am stuck what to write in my button onclick method:

```
    //this is from a file, but it has to be from sql server database like i do it in the console app above
    teacherList test = new cApp.teacherList("teachers.txt");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length < 1 | textBox2.Text.Length < 1 | textBox3.Text.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill all fields");
        }
        else
        {
            int id = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Teachers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (id < test.Teachers[i].Id)
                    id = test.Teachers[i].Id;
            }
            test.Workers.Add(new Teacher(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text));
            test.saveTeachersToDatabase();
            lbFill(test.Teachers);
            btnDelete.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it.  Create a new WinForms project and migrate your code into it

Comment: So your question is how to add the information of the teacher into Sql Server? It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: @MickyD I created a new WinForms Application and migrated code into it. I have one Teacher.cs file with all the functions and classes from the console app. And I have one Form1.cs where I have to call the methods from the buttons like the button1_Click event from above. The thing is I cannot connect both files to run properly.

Comment: Hi @Axel2D I have all the functionalities from the console app. However, when I create a new WinForms, I cannot connect the button events and the functions from the console app to run properly. Yes, my question is how to add the information of the teacher into Sql Server. I did that using a console app, but have trouble doing it using WinForms.

Comment: Ok, can you be more specific about the problem? Give us more information, what exactly is not working?

Comment: @Axel2D the else clause in the button1_Click event is not working. The code from public void AddTeacher(List<Teacher> Teachers) from the console app has to be in the else clause of the button1_Click event, but since it is a WinForms Application, I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: I see that in the console app you ask the user step by step the information about the teacher. If I understood correctly you want the 3 textBox in the form to contain the information. If so the only difference is in the fact that you get the information in a different way (textBox1.Text instead of Console.ReadLine()), adjust the code and it should work.

Comment: Ok. I will try it and will let you know my progress. Thanks.